# Calling method from MainWindow.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to call the following method from my MainWindow.xaml.cs but I'm not sure how to.

```
        public static string TileString(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            int[] tileInts = { x, y, z };
            string tileString = string.Join("/", tileInts);
            return tileString;
        }
```

The method is residing in a class with some functionality getting images from a database, and I want to update a textbox I have in the MainWindow with the name/id of those images. That functionality is working fine and it's being returned in the "tileString". However, I'm not sure how to couple it together with my MainWindow. Any hints? In the optimal world I would just be able to say (in MainWindow.xaml.cs) ServerOutPutTextBox.Appendtext(tileString); (the textbox I want it shown in) but it can't find it.

I'm imagining something like the following:

```
            public static string TileString(int x, int y, int z)
            {
                int[] tileInts = { x, y, z };
                string tileString = string.Join("/", tileInts);

                ServerOutPutTextBox.Appendtext(tilestring);
            }
```

Or somehow calling TileString in my MainWindow.xaml.cs.

EDIT: Here's the whole class.

```
public class Response
{
    public static string tileString;
    public static List<string> DbLocationList;
    public static HttpListener listener;
    public static void StartListening(List<string> prefixes, List<string> dbLocation)
    {
        if( listener  == null )
            listener = new HttpListener();

        //if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Count == 0)
        //    throw new ArgumentException("Prefixes missing.");

        DbLocationList = dbLocation;


        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }

        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequest), listener);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void OnRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //HttpListener listener = (HttpListener) result.AsyncState;
        if (listener == null)
            return;

        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequest), listener);

        string url = context.Request.RawUrl;

        string[] split = url.Split('/');

        int lastIndex = split.Length - 1;

        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        int x, y, z;
        string prefix;
        string dbPath = "";
        try
        {
            prefix = split[lastIndex - 3];
            x = Convert.ToInt32(split[lastIndex - 1]);
            y = Convert.ToInt32(split[lastIndex]);
            z = Convert.ToInt32(split[lastIndex - 2]);

            foreach (var path in DbLocationList)
            {
                string[] tmpStrings = path.Split('\\');
                string dbFn = tmpStrings[tmpStrings.Length-1];
                if (prefix == dbFn)
                {
                    dbPath = path;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // To extract from the database
            TilePicker picker = new TilePicker(dbPath);
            Image img = picker.GetTile(x, y, z);
            TileString(x, y, z);

            if (img == null)
            {
                response.StatusCode = 404;
                response.OutputStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // Load the image
                //Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(path);
                MemoryStream bmStream = new MemoryStream();
                //bm.Save(bmStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                img.Save(bmStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] buffer = bmStream.ToArray();


                // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
                response.ContentLength64 = bmStream.Length;
                response.ContentType = "image/png";
                response.KeepAlive = true;
                Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                // You must close the output stream.
                output.Close();
            }
                //listener.Stop();
            //}

            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            response.StatusCode = 404;
            response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
    }

    public static string TileString(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int[] tileInts = { x, y, z };
        string tileString = string.Join("/", tileInts);
        return tileString;
    }
}
```

Comment: How and where do you want to call it? Also, what is the name of the other class?

Comment: May i know in which class TileString method is residing?

Comment: @VenkyDhana It's in a class called Response.cs

I can edit in the whole class, but it's not relevant to this problem as far as I understand.

Comment: But it is. Static methods are called ClassName.StaticMethod( args )

Comment: @kenny I've edited in the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is, add a public method to the MainWindow and access that method from TileString:

```
// add this method to MainWindow
public void AppendServerOutput(string output)
{
    ServerOutPutTextBox.Appendtext(output);
}
```

and you can use it like:

```
public static string TileString(int x, int y, int z)
{
    ...

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
        mainWindow.AppendServerOutput(tileString);
    }));
}
```

Comment: I can see how this would work. But when I get to var mainWindow = ... I get an InvalidOperationException: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: While you were conjuring up this solution, I was reading about the Dispatcher. It works now!